# Why isn't there any general chat room for Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, chat

Occasionally I find myself wondering about some sort of issue, maybe just for or maybe someone else has it as well. Which is an issue, but not as small as just leave it be and as large, that it requires question even on Meta Stack Overflow.

It might be a dumb question, but why isn't there any chat room for Meta Stack Overflow? Is there actually such a small amount of people who will be interested in it?

Comment: Anyone can create a new chatroom. If there is no general chat room for Meta, that just means no-one felt the need to create one.

Comment: We used to have [The SO Tavern](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5/the-so-tavern-free-snacks) but we let it froze because it saw very little traffic. That room was not specific for Meta SO but I used it often to redirect lost users from SOCVR to that room.

Comment: I see. @MartijnPieters I see what you mean, just thought, that there actually would be more people, that felt same way as I do.

Comment: @rene totally forgot about that room, apparently I used to hang around there as well. But maybe it doesn't make a lot of sense to have both a MSE tavern and a SO tavern.

Comment: @Stijn yeah, a chatroom needs a stable and dedicated core of users that participate on regular basis. A room with only cat-gifs gets boring in the end, no matter how funny the cat-gifs. In the end I think we had only 5 or 6 regulars, that is not enough. That said, SOCVR is open for stuff related to moderating and I'm happy go help out any user that ask for general advice about Meta as most of the regulars there do patrol meta as well.

Comment: If the issue is not specific to SO / programming, the Tavern on the Meta (linked by rene below) is a good venue. They helped me with some UI issue I ran into a month or so ago.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> It might be a dumb question

No, not really.

> why isn't there any chat room for Meta Stack Overflow?

Because no one yet created and maintained such room for that specific goal.

> Is there actually such a small amount of people who will be interested in it?

I'm not sure, you can only know by trying.

Most chatrooms on SO have a specific topic or audience in mind. There was at least one chat room that had a general purpose nature, [The SO Tavern](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5/the-so-tavern-free-snacks) which was a bit modeled after its sister room on MSE, [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) for network-wide chatter.

The regulars of the SO Tavern, including myself as one of the Room Owners, lost interest, moved to other rooms or found more useful things to spend their time on and so the room was frozen due to inactivity.

There also was an [Stack Overflow Meta-Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/58982/stack-overflow-meta-room), with a bunch of moderators as RO's but it froze in February 2015. You might want to learn from the mods that frequented that room why it wasn't successful.

It is a good idea to head to chat first if there are trivial issues that are just unclear in the help, FAQ or meta posts. Most active chat rooms surely have regulars that are also familiar with Meta and I assume most rooms don't mind if you ask there. At worst they redirect you to someone who can help or they offer a better suited room.

If you have questions about moderation on main (voting, flagging, reviewing, editing, audits, tagging, burnination) you are welcomed in the [Stack Overflow Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) (SOCVR) chatroom. Our regulars are familiar names on Meta and we are happy to help out with questions around our room topic. Keep in mind though that we have an insane set of rulez (no [oneboxes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57286/which-links-and-sites-are-handled-specially-in-chat), no cat gifs), that can be found in our [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq). Before you join there you might want to take our [tour](https://socvr.org/tour). Be aware that the SOCVR doesn't moderate Meta, so you can't ask the room to close, re-open, flag, or otherwise perform moderation actions on meta posts. The Room Owners's will move such requests without warning. In that sense we moderate the room rather strictly. But our regulars don't bite, so feel free to drop by anytime.

Having said all this: Don't let this discourage you from starting a room if you feel like it. When you have settled in drop a line in the SOCVR and I'll be happy to advertise it on our Starboard.

Comment: Our regulars don't bite, except for that squirrel, and the unicorn is carnivorous.

Comment: One user felt that there was a need for such a room and created the [Stack Overflow Meta-Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/58982/stack-overflow-meta-room) as well. It froze 2 years back.

Comment: @BhargavRao only mods as RO's there. That is your problem ;)

Comment: What about unicorn gifs?