# Which chat is the main one for Stack Overflow, if any?

Tags: support, chat

You know how Stack Exchange sites tend to have a main chat that is always open (never frozen), and it stays that way forever — and how it was probably the first one to exist for the site?
(e.g.: for [Gardening and Landscaping](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=people&host=gardening.stackexchange.com), it's called "The Garden Shed")

What is the name of Stack Overflow's standard chat, if it has one? [I see a *lot* of chats](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/?tab=all&sort=people) (many with lots of activity), and no clues as to which one is the standard one.

Comment: There are no main chatrooms; SO has an [entire site](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) dedicated to SO chats, in addition to rooms using SO as the parent on chat.stackexchange.com

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348331/why-isnt-there-any-general-chat-room-for-meta-stack-overflow/348373#348373

Comment: What are you looking to chat about?

Comment: [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570). What else ?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I was previously under the impression that the main Stack Overflow chat would be precisely where to go to chat about whatever you want, with a loose focus on programming generally (not as a substitute for Q/A on site), but that it was also the place to go for sure for comments that are too chatty or off-topic.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Stack Overflow is *huge*—it gets something like 10 times the traffic of the biggest other SE site, and about half the total traffic for the network.

The "main" chatrooms as you describe them actually exist for [language](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c) [tags](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java), but if you want a "one huge eternal chatroom for the whole site" sort of thing, then we probably don't have that. Tavern on the Meta is that for Meta, but the main site just has too many sub-cultures for a single chatroom to unify.

Comment: We actually prefer not to talk too much about generic Meta topics on SOCVR, it's mostly about curating content.

Comment: There is a chat named ["General"](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3/general) (#3) but it's really, *really* inactive

Answer (score 14):

We've tried creating welcoming 'lobbies' in the past. The problem is, without some pre-defined consensus of what a topic *should* be, nobody really notices when things get so far out in the weeds that that the room actually becomes off-topic (and often unwelcoming, as new users are seen more as interruptions than anything).

I'm willing to try an "information desk" again if some other folks would be willing to give it an earnest go, because we could at least check the transcript to see if we've given advice to someone looking for help *using the sites or chat system*, but again, previous attempts at this just resulted in a stream of ad-hoc and vague programming questions under the guise of "where to ask this?".

Open to suggestions on something more sustainable but .. to date .. we've yet to come up with anything that stuck.

Comment: I'd expect a lobby like that to be riddled with trolls, so you should prepare with adequate moderation background to prevent it from becoming a cesspool. Also every once in a while we get users in tag-specific chatrooms asking about <thing> because "*I couldn't find a room for <thing>*". Take git questions for instance. I don't think this problem has a solution, my point is just that I also expect more or less disguised programming questions if such a lobby were to exist.

Comment: I'd be willing to hang out in such a lobby if it were clearly defined by the room owners that actual programming questions don't fly there and if the room had room owners to actually enforce that standard. It'd be nice to have a general "tell me how the site works a bit but not in a long comment chain" kind of room where newcomers can ask about common pitfalls and collaborate on improving their questions. Less formal then the mentorship project but could still work.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Such trolls would just be banned per the Terms of Service. Doesn't seem like much of a concern for me (it should be implicit in any chatroom, especially a 'site-wide default' chatroom that sufficient RO curation is expected -- even small rooms will get frozen [and some site-wide default rooms have been permafrozen before] for lack of acceptable RO behavior).

Comment: @TimPost I'd be willing to hang out and also help room-own such a room should one be created. I imagine the scope of programming questions, like Magisch said, would be "ask on main if you have a specific question, or if you just need a simple pointer, here's the room for that language", along with the general safety rules of "no politics, no religion, etc.". This could also be a good opportunity to tie in the tutoring thing SO has done recently; the tutors could hang out here and invite new users to 1-on-1 chats and help curate their first post(s) (also similar to Magisch's comment)

Comment: "help using the sites or chat system" - isn't that basically Meta, which is covered on ... well, Meta, or the Tavern? If anything, it might make sense to have a place for general discussion or opinion-based questions, but I'm not sure how many of such questions are language-agnostic (which are the only ones you can really post in a general room).