# I've discovered a bad tag, and am unsure what to do about it

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-system

After seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57420400/1843510), I've discovered the tag [smsautoverification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smsautoverification), which seems to have two completely different uses, the tag name is a mess, is not really used (4 questions, 0 answers, 0 votes) and it adds no information to the post and may even detract from it.

I have read through these two posts on burnination ([process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination), and [guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)) however they seem to leave one thing out: who can do it or how they should proceed if they can't do all of it.

I see burnination requests and they're commonly from people who seem quite active on Meta and who have large quantities of reputation; I am/have neither.

---

**Am I allowed to do this?** (stuff leading up to burnination: effectively dismantling the tag) (I understand different privileges come with different levels, and I am able to flag for closing of questions and edit to remove the tags, but if there are other ... meta rules about it) and **should *I* do it?**

The guide says I shouldn't even bother unless I have full editing rights, but then where should I raise a concern over the existence of this tag? Here, like I'm doing (but more specifically)?

Or should I follow the recommendation in the comments of the guide suggesting I ignore things I don't have the privileges to?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, let me clear up two important issues related to what you mention:

> two completely different uses

This is a valid reason to "disambiguate" the tag.

> the tag name is a mess

This is a valid reason to "rename" the tag.

So burnination of the tag is not the only way to go when we have issues with tags, there are other ways to resolve them too! These include disambiguations, retagging, renaming, synonymizing and merging. Anyway, that's for another question, another day.

---

Now getting back to the original question that you had:

> am I allowed to do this?

The answer is yes, you are! You are free to post any tag related requests on meta.

> The guide says I shouldn't even bother unless I have full editing rights, but then where should I raise a concern over the existence of this tag?

The guide mentions that you shouldn't bother with *retagging* until you get to the full editing privileges, you still can and must indeed post about any incorrect tags which you find.

Whenever you discover that a certain tag needs to burninated, post a [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) here detailing the reasons why you need to burninate the tag, preferably answering the 4 questions that are required for the burnination of a tag. Remember to always post a meta, no matter how small the tag is (except if there is 1 question). See [Tag removals must be discussed and documented on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356963/4099593). Users with any reputation level can post burnination requests.

The reason why we ask for <2k users to ignore is because it required 3 users to complete retagging one post (1 to edit and 2 to review), and even that is rate-limited. Therefore we prefer that you use your quota of suggested edits and the reviewers use their quota of suggested edit reviews on something that is more immediate and more meaningful. There already is a lot of questions coming in that are in dire need of edits, and the <2k users can spend their time better in curating those, instead of the posts in the tag that is getting burninated.

---

I also wanted to point out that there are plenty of places where you can help out *during* burninations, no matter at what privilege level you are. (Sorry for expanding outside what you had asked, I wanted to write this up since this was being asked by others too). Here's a handy table of what users with a certain privilege level usually do *during* burninations:

- 1 - 15 rep (smiling and waving):

  - Watch and learn as to how they can help out once they get to the next rep level.
- 15 - 2000 rep (flagging and suggesting) :

  - Flag the off-topic posts in that tag for closure using the standard close reasons, so that it will be pushed to the review queue.
  - Flag historically locked posts in that tag for moderator intervention and explain that the tag is being removed.
  - Suggest edits on the salvageable questions, only after making sure that they correct all the changes to the post and not just edit out the tag.
  - Suggest changes to the tag wiki and excerpts of the other tags that are created as a byproduct of the burnination effort.
- 2000 - 3000 rep (flagging and editing):

  - (1, 2 & 4 from the prev rep level)
  - Edit the post to remove the particular tag (and/or retag with more meaningful tags) from the questions with that tag.
- 3000 - 10000 rep (editing and closing):

  - (2 from the prev rep level)
  - Reviewing the close vote queue filtered on that tag to close the off topic questions in that tag.
  - Reviewing the reopen vote queue to reopen posts that were wrongly closed as off topic.
  - Voting to close the off-topic questions in the tag from outside the queues.
- 10000 - 15000 rep (editing, closing and deleting)

  - (all from the prev rep level)
  - Voting to delete the unsalvageable questions (This isn't required usually as the closed posts will be reviewed by Moderators at the end of the burnination effort)
- 15000 - 20000 rep (editing, closing, deleting and protecting)

  - (all from the prev rep level)
  - Protecting questions in the tag that have been receiving poor answers, after retagging.
- 20000 + rep

  - (all from the prev rep level)
  - Editing the tag wiki/excerpt of the tag to indicate that it is being burned.
  - Editing the tag wiki/excerpt of the other tags that are created during the burnination process.
  - Voting to delete the bad answers as they review the questions.
- ♦ Moderator

  - (all from the prev rep level)
  - Orchestrating the entire burnination process.
  - Constantly on the lookout for users without the full edit privilege who are just removing the tags in the suggested edits, and educating them.
  - Constantly on the lookout for users with the close vote privilege who are blatantly voting to close valid/on-topic posts
  - Reviewing the closed questions at the end to either delete/reopen
- ♦♦ CM

  - Handling concerns with respect to any backlashes faced during the burnination process, with respect to revenge downvoting.
  - Mass adding a tag to the posts.
  - Purging the tag at the end in the case of very large burns.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I particularly appreciate the details on what different users can do. Is there a guide / information about disambiguation vs burninating vs retagging vs synonymizing vs renaming vs merging? I can't even find information similar to I did about burnination for the other types. I imagine a couple of these types may well lead up to a burnination, but I'd hate to do that without following the respective rules on that.

Comment: @zbee None that I know of, as of now. I did write some stuff on a gist a few weeks back https://gist.github.com/Bhargav-Rao/220b47a45354dd4a796fbc6c15203ae0, but nothing comprehensive. We certainly need to write them down somewhere.

Comment: Maybe it's another thing to write out :) I can make sense of that; thank you. So I should start with a disambiguation / retagging before making a burnination request, if so which?

Comment: @zbee, Nope, if the tag needs a burnination, we need to start with one. You can easily figure out if a tag needs burnination by trying to answer out the 4 questions. If you answer "Yes" to any one of them, then there's a very high chance that you need a disambiguation, or a retag. I get it that it isn't the very best system that we have to get easily onboarded onto, when we are learning ... so feel free to ask any questions you have in chat. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388117/4099593